# ¿Cómo renombrar el encabezado de algunos archivos con un diccionario cuyas claves son un poco diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, diccionarios, dataframe

Me gustaría renombrar el encabezado de algunos archivos y hacer la suma de las columnas que eventualmente se agruparían. En efecto, tengo un archivo con nombres, resultados y extra metadatas, y otro archivo que mapea entre los nombres de los encabezados y los nombres deseados. Por ejemplo, aquí está una parte del archivo de datos :

```
TEXT,# 1 - A, # 12 - B,# 13 - C,# 3 - D
a,         1,        1,       1,      2
b,         1,        1,       1,      2
c,         1,        1,       1,      2
d,         1,        1,       1,      2
```

y el otro archivo `mapping.csv` que mapea entre los nombres de los archivos, pero menos `# numero -`, y los nombres deseados

```
old,new
A,A
B,A
C,A
D,D
E,D
F,D
G,G
H,G
I,G
```

Me gustaria obtener :

```
TEXT,      A,      D
a,         3,      2
b,         3,      2
c,         3,      2
d,         3,      2
```

También tengo otro archivo con mapeo parcial pero no completo como..:

```
old,     new
# 1 - A,   A
# 12 - B,  A
C,         A
```

As one can see the names in the header won't exactly match the `old` column but might rather be included. Indeed, they all have a `# number - NAME` pattern before in `aggregate.csv` file whereas they only have `NAME` in the `mapping.csv`.

Por el momento lo intenté:

```
file = 'mapping.csv'
dictionary = pd.read_csv(file)

header_map = dictionary.set_index("old").to_dict()["new"]

df = pd.read_csv("aggregate.csv")
df = df.rename(columns in header_map)
```

Como las columnas no son exactamente iguales, ¿cómo puedo añadir cuando hay los mismos nombres en el diccionario?

Así que lo intenté:

```
import csv 
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('mapping.csv')

df = pd.read_csv("aggregate.csv")

for column in range(0,len(df.columns)):
     for line in range(0,len(file.index)):
        if file.iloc(line,1) in df.iloc(1,column):
            df.iloc(1,column) = file.iloc(line,2)
```

Pero devuelve :

```
  File "<ipython-input-35-42dc8c6bc966>", line 15
    df.iloc(1,column) = file.iloc(line,2)
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Hola, he leído tu pregunta varias veces pero no logro comprender qué quieres hacer. Si pudieras explicar un poco más o poner un ejemplo con datos más simplificados (tal vez con nombres de columnas cortos) podria ser mas claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, esto te puede servir. He creado un ejemplo simplificado:

Con el archivo de datos (data.csv):

```
TEXT,#1 - A,#12 - B,#21 - C,#2 - D,#23 - E,#13 - F,#3 - G,#14 - H,#24 - I
a,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
b,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
c,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
d,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
e,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
f,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
g,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
h,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
i,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
j,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
```

y el archivo de mapeo (map.csv):

```
old,new
A,A
B,A
C,A
D,D
E,D
F,D
G,G
H,G
I,G
```

Se necesita primero eliminar el patron `"#X - "` de las columnas. Luego reemplazar los nombres de las columnas en el archivo de datos según el mapeo del archivo map.csv, y luego agrupar y sumar las columnas con el mismo nombre.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'map.csv'
dictionary = pd.read_csv(file)

header_map = dictionary.set_index("old").to_dict()["new"]

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
# Renombra eliminando el patron '#X - '
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'#[0-9]* - (.*)',r'\1',x))
# Usa el archivo de mapeo para renombrar
df = df.rename(columns = header_map)

df_sum = df.T.reset_index().groupby("index").sum().T    
df_sum
```

Con el código anterior, el resultado sería:

```
index  A  D  G TEXT
0      3  6  9    a
1      3  6  9    b
2      3  6  9    c
3      3  6  9    d
4      3  6  9    e
5      3  6  9    f
6      3  6  9    g
7      3  6  9    h
8      3  6  9    i
9      3  6  9    j
```

Espero que esto te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Como hacerlo si no tengo `TEXT,A,B,...` pero `TEXT, #1 - A, #12 - B, ...` ?

Comment: Lo he probado con el encabezado `TEXT, #1 - A, #12 - B, #21 - C,D,E,F,G,H,I` y ajustando el mapeo, y funcionó igual.

Comment: Entonces `#1 - A` coincide con `A` por ejemplo ?

Comment: A qué te refieres con "coincide"? He actualizado la pregunta con esta ultima modificación

Comment: Quiero decir, lo que me molesta es el patrón `# número -` de la que quiero deshacerme.

Comment: tal vez puedo hacer `df.columns = [col.replace(' # número -', '') for col in df.columns]` pero necesito los números.

Comment: Listo, creo que ya entendí. Actualicé de nuevo la respuesta.

Comment: gracias, pido perdón si no fue claro

Comment: Hola Gustavo ! Como estas ? Tuve [un problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303630/tipos-de-operando-no-soportados-para-int-y-str-al-renombrar-columnas) con el renombramiento de las columnas con su método. ¿Tienes tiempo para echar un vistazo?